# Memory allocation for a three dimensional structure

Tags: memory, structure

In the following piece of code, I would like to include a third dimension to the structure. The structure genotype and the rest of the identifiers are already defined. 
This works with no problems:

```
struct genotype ** populationrows = (struct genotype **) calloc(MAXGENS, sizeof(struct genotype *));

  for (k=0; k< MAXGENS; k++) {

    populationrows[k]= (struct genotype *) calloc (POPSIZE, sizeof (struct genotype));  

    for (j=0; j<2; j++) {
      for (i=0; i<3; i++) { 
        populationrows[k][j].fitness = 0;
        populationrows[k][j].rfitness = 0;
        populationrows[k][j].cfitness = 0;
        populationrows[k][j].lower[i] = 1.0;
        populationrows[k][j].upper[i]= 2.0;
        populationrows[k][j].gene[i] = 3.0;
        printf(" populationrows[%u][%u].gene[%u]=%25lf \n", k,j,i,populationrows[k][j].gene[i]); 
      }
    }   
  }
```

And for the third dimension I tried the following:

struct genotype * ** populationrows = (struct genotype * **) calloc(numFiles, sizeof(struct genotype * *));

for (w=0; w< numFiles; w++){

populationrows[w]= (struct genotype **) calloc (MAXGENS, sizeof (struct genotype *));

```
for (k=0; k<MAXGENS; k++) {    
  for (j=0; j<2; j++) {
    for (i=0; i<3; i++) {   
      populationrows[w][k][j].fitness = 0;
      populationrows[w][k][j].rfitness = 0;
      populationrows[w][k][j].cfitness = 0;
      populationrows[w][k][j].lower[i] = 1.0;
      populationrows[w][k][j].upper[i]= 2.0;
      populationrows[w][k][j].gene[i] = 3.0;
      printf(" populationrows[%u][%u][%u].gene[%u]=%25lf \n", w,k,j,i,populationrows[w][k][j].gene[i]); 
    }
  }     
 }  
}
```

But this gives me a Segmentation fault.

Would you mind telling me how to avoid this segmentation fault?
Any help will be very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance for your response!!!

Comment: If you're using three level of indirection, you also need three levels of allocation. But do consider replacing this by a flat array with some smart indexing -- you don't want to become a [three star programmer](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that it's C.

Instead of an array of pointers pointing to pointers to data better use a flat array. Something like that:

```
int n_w = 42, n_k = 23, n_j = 423; // size of dimensions

struct genotype * population = (struct genotype *) calloc(n_w * n_k * n_j, sizeof(struct genotype));
```

You're getting element (10, 11, 12) then with:

```
population[10 * n_k * n_j + 11 * n_j + 12].fitness = 0;
```

It's getting pretty if you put that into functions:

```
int n_w = 42, n_k = 23, n_j = 423; // size of dimensions

struct genotype * create_array() {
    return (struct genotype *) calloc(n_w * n_k * n_j, sizeof(struct genotype));
}

struct genotype * get_element(int w, int k, int j) {
    return &population[w * n_k * n_j + k * n_j + j];
}

// ...

struct genotype * population = create_array();

get_element(10, 11, 12)->fitness = 0;
```